# I am using Kaggle FIFA19 dataset . How can i find The best player per position and list them?

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am using Kaggle FIFA19 dataset. How can I find The best player per position and list them?

I am using python

```
df.groupby('Position').agg({'Overall': 'avg'}).sort('avg(Overall)', ascending=False).show()
```

I need to list the name of players in another column

Answer (score 1):

Why not grouping on name and position both

```
df.groupby('Name','Position').agg({'Overall': 'avg'}).sort('avg(Overall)', ascending=False).show()
```

Comment: I tried but i am getting two entries of Goal keeper because both of them have the same overall rating

Comment: This is expected.. If they have same rating then they both should come